# htaccess redirect with RedirectMatch

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm adding 301 redirect to my website, here is the htaccess content :

```
    RedirectMatch ^/gift/birthday/(.*) /gifts.html
```

the result in my browser is :

```
    http://www.website.com/gifts.htmlbirthday/
```

and I want :

```
    http://www.website.com/gifts.html
```

How can I do that ?

EDIT : my htaccess is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

RedirectMatch ^/gift/birthday/(.*) /gifts.html
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is that the only rule you have in your htaccess file?

Comment: Try cleaning your browser cache

Comment: No it's not the only one, see my htaccess above. (I already clean my cache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix *mod_rewrite* rules and *mod_alias* directives like this, they are not processed in the order from the .htaccess, but separately as they are handled by different apache modules.

What you need is something like this:

```
# this is not mod_rewrite rule so it can be outside the IfModule
Options +FollowSymLinks

# all mod_rewrite rules go here
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# initialize mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# your redirect
RewriteRule ^gift/birthday/  http://www.website.com/gifts.html [R=301,L]

# copy&paste the rest of your htaccess below, just delete that RedirectMatch line
# ...
```

This RewriteRule does the 301 redirect from any url that starts with gift/birthday/ to a fixed url /gifts.htm. Letter [L] means to skip the rest of the rules if this one is matched.

Don't forget to close the set of rules with < /IfModule > at the end.